# compass lucene search results sorting

Tags: full-text-search, lucene, compass-lucene

I almost successfully implemented compass lucene search in my web application.I am searching for a customer with his name. For example in the below screenshot , I am searching for a customer with *RAM* and below are the results. But there is a small problem,The results shown are not sorted for Names with RAM..it shows all customer names that have the three letters RAM in any position in their name.

I want all my results of Customer Name to start with Letters Ram*...
Can anyone guide me how to get results that start with letters RAM.

It should return results like a database search for eg: " Where customername like 'RAM%'

### My Analyzer is this

```
<searchEngine>
          <analyzer name="default" type="Simple">
              <stopWords>
                  <stopWord value="test" />
              </stopWords>
          </analyzer>
    </searchEngine>
```

### This is my annotated field for Customer First name in my entity class.

```
    @SearchableProperty
@SearchableMetaData(name = "customerFirstName")
private String customerFirstName;
```

[image: search screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Just don't start it with a star. "*RAM*" will be anything than includes "RAM". "RAM*" will be things that start with "RAM."

Comment: nops.. without giving * at the beginning also gives the same result.There must be some way to sort the search results. I think here compass is giving me relevant results..like google search..which is correct. but what I want is exact search..something like a database search for example  'where customername like 'RAM%''